# Determine when a ScheduledExecutorService will fire next

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to determine the current millisecond or other time measure of when a ScheduledExecutorService is going to fire next?

```
scheduleTaskExecutorUpdate = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

I have a longer running `ScheduledExecutorService(A)` and from a shorter running `ScheduledExecutorService(B)` I would like to update a TextView, display a countdown of when `ScheduledExecutorService(A)` is going to fire next.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you keep track of the [`ScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html)s for all tasks scheduled with the executor, then yes. This becomes a problem of determining the minimum delay until the next task must fire, which should be a fairly reliable estimate.

```
final Collection<ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = ...;
/* for each schedule, add it to the above collection */
...
final long delay = Collections.min(futures).getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

... or, for one task, you merely do:

```
final ScheduledFuture<?> future = ...;
final long delay = future.getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Now, if you're going to be doing it *a lot*, with mutiple tasks, I'd suggest you maintain a [`DelayQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html). However, you can't merely throw the `ScheduledFuture`s in the queue without maintaining the changes caused by periodic tasks. Luckily, the class [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor%28int%29) should handle this nicely via its [`decorateTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#decorateTask(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture)) methods.

Note this means you will need to create your own`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` directly. Something like the below might work.

```
public class TrackingSingleThreadScheduledExecutor
    extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

  private final DelayQueue<ScheduledFuture<?>> tasks
      = new DelayQueue<RunnableScheduledFuture<?>>();

  public TrackingSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() {
    super(1);
  }

  public DelayQueue<? extends ScheduledFuture<V>> tasks() {
    return tasks;
  }

  public ScheduledFuture<V> next() {
    return tasks.peek();
  }

  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask
      (final Callable<V> callable, final RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    return new QueueAwareTask(task);
  }

  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask
      (final Runnable runnable, final RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    return new QueueAwareTask(task);
  }

  private final class QueueAwareTask<V> implements RunnableScheduledFuture<V> {

    private final RunnableScheduledFuture<V> inner;

    public QueueAwareTask(final RunnableScheduledFuture<V> inner) {
      this.inner = inner;
    }

    public boolean isPeriodic() {
      return inner.isPeriodic();
    }

    public long getDelay(final TimeUnit unit) {
      return inner.getDelay(unit);
    }

    public void run() {
      inner.run();
      if (queue.remove(inner) && inner.isPeriodic()
          && !inner.isCancelled()) {
        queue.add(inner);
      }
    }

    public int compareTo(final Delayed other) {
      return inner.compareTo(other);
    }

    public boolean cancel(final boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
      final boolean cancelled = inner.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
      if (cancelled) {
        queue.remove(inner);
      }
      return cancelled;
    }

    public boolean isCancelled() {
      return inner.isCancelled();
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
      return inner.isDone();
    }

    public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      return inner.get();
    }

    public V get(final long timeout, final TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      return inner.get(timeout, unit);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, usage is as follows.

```
final TrackingSingleThreadScheduledExecutor executor
    = new TrackingSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
...
final long delay = executor.next().getDelay(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: @RNJ hopefully it's an even better solution now!